# Is there a intutive reason as to why the below fact is true?

Tags: inequality

Suppose we are given postive real numbers a,b,c,d,e all which sum to 1 (that is a+b+c+d+e=1) we need to maximize the sum 4a+b+c+2d+e  , why is it true that in maximum/minimum case the b,c,e term should have values all equal?  Just intuitive reason

Comment: if you want to see this kind of thing in a much wider perspective, read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581849/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions and especially [the article linked there by William Waterhouse](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Waterhouse378-387.pdf)

Comment: @MatthewTowers thanks thats what i was wanting too

Comment: More generally, for a function $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ where $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=f(x_2,x_1,\dots,x_n),$ we know given any minimum at $(x_1’,\dots,x_n’),$ there is a minimum also at $(x_2’,x_1’,\dots,x_n’).$ So if there is something about $f$ which makes the minimum point unique, we get $x_1’=x_2’.$ But the symmetry doesn’t guarantee this - you need symmetry in addition to other properties of $f.$

Comment: I see thanks @ThomasAndrews